# on the Rayleigh's inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of a graph with $n$ vertices, $e$ edges and eigenvalues $\lambda_n \leq \cdots \leq \lambda_1$.
I know that by Rayleigh's inequality, $$\frac{x^T Ax}{x^T x}\leq \lambda_1, \quad \forall x\in \mathbb{R}^n\smallsetminus\{\textbf{0}\}.$$
Does Rayleigh's inequality imply that $$\frac{2e}{n}\leq \lambda_1\,?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, to see this, we just have to let $x$ be the all one vector.

$x^TAx$ would sum up all the entries of $A$ which gives us $2e$ while $x^Tx=n$.

Comment: @SionThyeGoh That's true. Thank you for your answer.